# How to save selected layers in RasterBrick and save it as a tiff in R?

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have  rasterbrick

```
> BRICK1
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 68, 89, 6052, 150  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : 60.75, 105.25, 5.75, 39.75  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : Veg_1551, Veg_1552, Veg_1553, Veg_1554, Veg_1555, Veg_1556, Veg_1557, Veg_1558, Veg_1559, Veg_1560, Veg_1561, Veg_1562, Veg_1563, Veg_1564, Veg_1565, ... 
min values : -0.91900, -1.06400, -1.09100, -1.07600, -1.01200, -0.95900, -1.03300, -1.09500, -1.08500, -1.04100, -1.04500, -1.00900, -1.01100, -1.04100, -1.09800, ... 
max values :  0.00000,  0.10700,  0.02400,  0.01400,  0.00600,  0.00000,  0.04300,  0.04000,  0.01300,  0.00300,  0.02500,  0.02100,  0.00000,  0.02900,  0.01000, ...
```

It has layers from 1551 to 1565. How can I save a rasterstack as tiff file including only Veg_1551 to Veg_1561?

I am trying to plot by

`plot(Veg_1551:Veg_1561)` however it returns an error. Kindly guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subset` function to select specific layers or bands and then you can plot or write subsetted image like

```
library(raster)

#Load an image
logo <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
plot(logo)

#Select first 2 bands only
logosub <- subset(logo, 1:2)
#Or
logosub <- subset(logo, c("red", "blue" ))
plot(logosub)

#Write the subsetted raster
writeRaster(logosub, "Subset_raster.tif")
```

**Edit**

You can create a sequence of string or character names as

```
prefix <- "Veg"
suffix <- seq(1551, 1561, 1)
layers <- paste(prefix, suffix, sep = "_")
```

Then use it for subsetting the `RasterBrick` as

```
BRICK1_sub <- subset(BRICK1, layers)

#Write the subsetted raster
writeRaster(BRICK1_sub, "Subset_raster.tif")
```

Comment: is there any command like logosub <- subset(logo, c("red":"blue" )) ? Because the layers have names, like Veg_1551 , Veg_1552..so on.

Comment: Please see my update. Hope that helps you out.